# Правильно ли я решил поставленную задачу?

Tags: java

Формулировка задачи была следующая:[image: Формулировка задачи]
Решение автора было таким: [image: Решение автора]
Я решил задачу немного другими способами
Способ 1 :[image: Решение1]
Способ 2:[image: Решение2]
Я первый раз пользуюсь сайтом, если криво составил вопрос - простите и поправьте.
Также, принимаю замечания по оформлению кода. Спасибо огромное, заранее!)

Comment: Весь код стОит вставлять форматированным текстом....текст задачи тоже, в виде цитаты

Comment: Если результаты правильные, то и решение правильное.

Comment: автор демонстрировал алгоритм решения, Ваше решение тоже резонно, но иногда задача - просто задача) Ваше решение менее гибкое - будет работать только для строк, решение автора хотя и не идеальное можно расширить до объектов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оба ваших варианта используют один подход: преобразовать объекты `StringBuilder` в строки и сравнивать уже их с помощью доступного метода `equals`. Также вариант решения, но оставлю пару комментариев.

1. Первый из предложенных вами вариант работает неверно. Например

   ```
    StringBuilder kot = new StringBuilder("kot");
    StringBuilder kod = new StringBuilder("kod");
    boolean isEqual = kot.substring(0, kot.length() - 1)
        .equals(kod.substring(0, kod.length() - 1));
    System.out.println(isEqual);
   ```

выведит `true`. Т.к при сравнении отбрасывается последний символ.

2. Метод `equals` возвращает `boolean` тип. Поэтому возвращать в тернарном операторе true, когда выражение истино и `false`, когда ложно - лишнее. Результат метода equals можно сразу записать в переменную `result`;

   ```
    boolean result = sb1.toString().equals(sb2.toString());
   ```
3. Выводить в консоль возвращаемое значение наверное не стоит. Лучше получить его в main методе и уже там его вывести.
4. Исходя из второго и третьего пункта - можно убрать переменную `result` и сразу вернуть результат работы `equals`

   ```
    return sb1.toString().equals(sb2.toString());
   ```

Про именование. Если посмотреть пункт [5 Naming](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming) из Google Java Style Guide, то для имени пакета следует использовать только строчные буквы (course.lesson17), а класс начинать с прописной (Homework).

Comment: Спасибо большое! Предельно понятно! Спасибо!